# Android 8 (API 26) : "colorControlHighlight" color is coming over contents

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have set the app theme as `<itemname="colorControlHighlight">@color/app_accent</item>`
and applying it in AndroidMainfest.xml by `<application android:theme="@style/NormalTheme">`
In other API it is working fine, but when I am running the app in android 8, the color of `colorControlHighlight` is coming over the screen like this

[image]

In activity:

`shelfViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
shelfViewPager.setAdapter(newShelfPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), data));`

I found this part of the view in xml file, is keep on highlighting during the rendering process

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/shelf"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: The header and the "arrow" on the screenshot they are fine, but there are some contents which are in the middle part of the screen, where transparent blue screen is overlapping those contents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research found a part in Android API 27 or higher, called `drawDefaultFocusHighlight` at the end of the draw method. As a result, it is applying the DefaultHighlight color automatically.
Setting this value to false worked fine.

You can know more about this in the following Documentation - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setDefaultFocusHighlightEnabled(boolean)

Comment: Genius! Thank you! I called setDefaultFocusHighlightEnabled(false) on the root parent of my layout